# Keyboard layout switching by itself when I click emacs window

Tags: keyboard-layout, emacs

I use various language-learning and dictionary websites and maintain multiple language glossaries using emacs, so I switch keyboard layouts frequently (using Super-Space or the pulldown menu). This all works well. But it often switches on its own when I click on any part of the emacs window. It apparently thinks it knows better than I do which layout I want. I ONLY want the keyboard layout to change when I explicitly ask it to. How can I fix this? This is Ubuntu 20.10 and Emacs 27.1.

Update: After upgrading to 21.04, the reported behavior appears to have ceased. So the answer to my question "How can I fix this?" is perhaps "Upgrade to 21.04".

Comment: Is "Use the same source for all windows" selected in _Settings -> Region & Language -> Input Sources -> \[cog wheel]_?

Comment: @Gunnar Yes, it is.